# Make GCC to call pthread_exit while transforming OpenMP parallel code

Tags: c, gcc, openmp, libgomp

I just found that gcc's OpenMP implementation (libgomp) doesn't call pthread_exit().
I need that to use perfsuite (for profiling).

Is there any way to tell GCC to include pthread_exit() at the end of a parallel section of OpenMP while transforming the OpenMP code to pthread codes?

I am using GCC 4.7.0 and Perfsuite 1.1.1 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`libgomp` implements thread pools. Once created, a thread in the pool remains idle until it is signalled to become member of a thread team. After the team finishes its work, the thread goes into an idle loop until it is signalled again. The pool grows on demand but never shrinks. Threads are only signalled to exit at program finish.

You can read the `libgomp` code that implements thread pools and teams in the 4.7.x branch [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/branches/gcc-4_7-branch/libgomp/team.c).

Pool threads are terminated like this: `libgomp` registers a destructor by the name of `team_destructor()`. It is called whenever the `main()` function returns, `exit(3)` gets called or the `libgomp` library is unloaded by a call to `dlclose(3)` (if previously loaded with `dlopen(3)`). The destructor deletes one `pthreads` key by the name of `gomp_thread_destructor`, which has an associated destructor function `gomp_free_thread()` triggered by the deletion. `gomp_free_thread()` makes all threads in the pool execute `gomp_free_pool_helper()` as their next task. `gomp_free_pool_helper()` calls `pthread_exit(3)` and thus all threads in the pool cease to exist.

Here is the same process in a nice ASCII picture:

```
main() returns, exit() called or library unloaded
  |
  |
team_destructor() deletes gomp_thread_destructor
  |
  |
gomp_free_thread() called by pthreads on gomp_thread_destructor deletion
  |
  +-------------------------+---------------------------+
  |                         |                           |
gomp_free_pool_helper()   gomp_free_pool_helper() ... gomp_free_pool_helper()
 installed as next task    installed as next task      installed as next task
  |                         |                           |
  |                         |                           |
pthread_exit(NULL)        pthread_exit(NULL)      ... pthread_exit(NULL)
```

Note that this only happens once at the end of the program execution and not at the end of each `parallel` region.

Comment: Hi Hristo, Thank you for the answer. As far as I understood, when the program exits i.e. the thread gets the signal, it doesn't call pthread_exit(). It seems like I need to change the code for this file (team.c) to do this. Is that right? If it is, is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: Threads run the loop in the second half of `gomp_thread_start()` as long as they have a function to execute after the docking barrier, otherwise they exit the loop and simply return. There is one case when threads call `pthread_exit` and that is the case when `libgomp` was loaded at runtime with `dlopen(3)`. There is one key `gomp_thread_destructor` with an associated destructor  `gomp_free_thread()` and a file destructor by the name of `team_destructor()` is registered. When you `dlclose(3)` the library, the file destructor get called and it makes all team threads call `pthread_exit`.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - functions with `__attribute__((destructor))` are also called after `main()` returns. It means that pool threads would surely reach the point where they call `pthread_exit` but not before the `main` function has returned. Unfortunately the `libgomp` API is not available to the user and you cannot invoke the pool destructor before the end of `main()`.

Comment: Very nice explanation!! I want to try loading at runtime. But I haven't done that before. If possible, could you please give some suggestion or example code for me to start with?

Comment: Read the manual page of `dlopen(3)` or just search the Internet on run-time library loading and symbol resolution. There are plenty of examples. Then you can find a reference on how different OpenMP constructs are implemented using `libgomp` in the [libgomp ABI reference](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/The-libgomp-ABI.html). The different function prototypes can be found in `libgomp.h` in the GCC source tree. You would need the prototypes in order to do the correct cast of symbol addresses that you obtain via calls to `dlsym(3)`.

Comment: Actually it's possible to shrink thread pool size by forcing `gomp_team_start` to be called with `nthreads` == 2 (1 will not work): https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/releases/gcc-4.7/libgomp/team.c#L340